# AP Calculus BC - Related Rates Problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide explanations, and I'd really, really appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem.

> A boy is standing on a dock watching a boat moving north away from him at a speed of $5000$ ft/min. A girl is standing $1000$ ft east of the boy and is watching the same boat. How fast is the boat moving away from the girl when it is $12500$ ft away from the boy? (Calculator allowed).

My thought process was as such:

We're looking for the derivative of the distance between the girl and the boat. The distance is the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle formed between the boat, boy, and girl - which is $\sqrt {(5000t)^2 + 1000^2}$.

However, when I wrote out the derivative and plugged in the value for t
(when the boat is $12500$ ft away from the boy, $t=\frac {12500}{5000}=2.5$), I didn't get the correct answer.

Any help (with steps shown) would be really amazing.

Comment: Hint:  often it simplifies the computation if you work with distance squared.  Thus, let $f(t)=(5000t)^2+1000^2$.

Comment: @lulu doesn't the f(t) have to be squared, too? Does that mean when I take the derivative of f(t)^2 I get 2f(t) * f'(t)?

Comment: Well, if $d(t)$ is the distance (your square root function) then my $f(t)$ is indeed $d^2(t)$.  You want $d'(t^*)$  but $f'(t^*)=2d(t^*)d'(t^*)$ so it is easy to work with $f(t)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

If boy stands at A and the girl stands at B.

At any point in the north O after a time t,

$$OA = 5000t$$

If this has to be equal to 12500 and you are right in getting $t = 2.5$

$$OB = \sqrt{(5000t)^2 + 1000^2}$$

$$\frac{dOB}{dt} = \frac{5000^2(2)t}{2\sqrt{(5000t)^2 + 1000^2}} = 4984.07\text{ft/min}$$

Comment: thank you both for your help! :]

Answer (score 1):

Following my suggestion in the comments:

We let $$f(t)=d^2(t)=(5000t)^2+1000^2\implies f'(t)=2d(t)d'(t)=2*5000^2t$$

plugging in $t=2.5$ we get $$d'(2.5)=\frac {5000^2\times 2.5}{d(2.5)}=4984.07639$$

Comment: thank you both for your help! :]